Is Mudblazor checked option dead
I have a MudCheckBox that i reference in my code in order to be able to know if i need to check it by default or no.
The thing is that when i use the myCheckBox.Checked = true, i ahve an error telling me that Checked is now obsolete and that i need to use Value.
But when i use my_checkBox.Value, it just tell me that i cant set it outside of the component
I just tried both of the answer but none seems to work
if (_account != null)
{
    _checkAvailable.Checked = ((int)_account.Attributes) % 2 > 0;
    _nullAccount = false;
}


Post code as text, not as a picture.

Your description is not so easy to follow, create a [mre] to explain what you want.

The "Checked" attribute was obsolete. With Mudblazor v7, many obsolete attributes has been removed. https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/releases/tag/v7.0.0

You should be able to do simple parameter binding and default the value to true.
<MudCheckBox @bind-Value="CheckBox1" />

@code {
    public bool CheckBox1 { get; set; } = true;
}

Of course instead of setting the property directly like this you'd do it in your method using whatever calculation you require.

Thanks, whats the differenece between @bind-value and just

Also how can i call a Valuechanged when the value is binded

You can't call value changed when using bind-Value because bind-Value utilizes value changed itself. Which also answers your other question somewhat.... bind-Value automatically calls value changed and updates the MudCheckBox.Value when using just Value you'd have to call value changed yourself.

Thanks, i found a way to do this with
                        <MudCheckBox T="bool" @bind-Value="_valOther" @bind-Value:after="switchModification" Label="Test_checkbox" />

